# Python calcul distance from gps coordinates

Tags: python, gps

I want to calculate the distance and find the nearest point located within a distance of less than 10m using GPS coordinates stored in two different CSV files. The point A in CSV 1 needs to be searched to see if there is a corresponding point within a distance of less than 10m in CSV 2.
Please could someone help me ?

I tried a python program that compute but is inefficient and doesn’t give good result.

Comment: You should define the format of the co-ordinates and show an example, show the code you have tried and explain why you consider the results this gives to be inefficient and 'not good;.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Comment: Check "degree of latitude" and ".. of longitude" in wikipedia. You can get how much it is on your initial location (in meter), so you do the proportion (you have much less then the one degree), It is very easy. so you have the cartesian coordinates, which you can calculate distance very easily)